# Getting Webalizer to show URL stats for all time, not by month

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, webalizer

The conf file has this section:

```
AllSites    yes
AllURLs yes
AllReferrers    yes
AllAgents   yes
AllSearchStr    yes
AllUsers       yes
```

...which is great, but I don't see any way to show the same sort of thing but for the entire timespan the log file covers.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the preferred way, but I guess for this purpose I can do a separate analysis without dates by regex-replacing all the dates with a single date.